# R "Merge" to columns in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I need your help in one of my R-Scripts.

I have a df that looks compareable to this:

```
X1 X2  X3 
1  123 NA
2  125 125
3  210 NA
4  NA  212
5  214 213
6  NA  225
```

I need to somehow merge X2 and X3 that every "NA" in X2 is subsetted with the value of X3
The df should then look like this:

```
X1 X2 
1  123 
2  125 
3  210 
4  212 
5  214 
6  225
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does this accomplish what you want `df$X2 <- ifelse(!is.na(df$X2), df$X2, df$X3)` ?

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `dplyr` you can do the following using `coalesce`. This will fill in missing `NA` in column `X2` with values from `X3`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(X2 = coalesce(X2, X3))
```

**Output**

```
  X1  X2  X3
1  1 123  NA
2  2 125 125
3  3 210  NA
4  4 212 212
5  5 214 213
6  6 225 225
```

Answer (score 1):

This will replace the NA values

```
df$X2[is.na(df$X2)] <- df$X3[is.na(df$X2)]
```

then we can remove X3 column with

```
df <- df[,-3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[<-` to overwrite `NA` detected by `is.na`.

```
i <- is.na(x$X2)
#i <- which(is.na(x$X2)) #Alternative
x$X2 <- "[<-"(x$X2, i, x$X3[i])
#x$X2[i] <- x$X3[i] #Alternative
x$X3 <- NULL
x
#  X1  X2
#1  1 123
#2  2 125
#3  3 210
#4  4 212
#5  5 214
#6  6 225
```

Benchmark:

```
set.seed(42)
n <- 1e6
tt <- seq_len(n)
y <- data.frame(X1=tt, X2=tt, X3=tt)
y$X2[sample(tt, n %/% 5)] <- NA
y$X3[sample(tt, n %/% 5)] <- NA

library(tidyverse) #For Ben
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(setup = {x <- y}
, GKi = {i <- is.na(x$X2)
x$X2 <- "[<-"(x$X2, i, x$X3[i])
x$X3 <- NULL}
, GKi2 = {i <- which(is.na(x$X2))
x$X2 <- "[<-"(x$X2, i, x$X3[i])
x$X3 <- NULL}
, GKi3 = {i <- which(is.na(x$X2))
x$X2[i] <- x$X3[i]
x$X3 <- NULL}
, OttoKaessi = {x$X2 <- ifelse(!is.na(x$X2), x$X2, x$X3)
  x$X3 <- NULL} #Added
, DanielO = {x$X2[is.na(x$X2)] <- x$X3[is.na(x$X2)]
  x <- x[,-3]}
, Ben = {x %>% mutate(X2 = coalesce(X2, X3))
  x$X3 <- NULL} #Added
, control=list(order="block"))
#Unit: milliseconds
#       expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
#        GKi  7.103401  7.201073  9.812947  8.329747  9.670540 135.0823   100  a 
#       GKi2  5.538879  5.592595  7.640384  5.661441  7.935306 132.6357   100  a 
#       GKi3  5.543583  5.614935  7.787013  5.709262  7.967789 133.1286   100  a 
# OttoKaessi 20.123728 22.516887 29.823813 23.226925 24.818421 152.3072   100   b
#    DanielO  8.109087  8.381130 12.448476 10.622454 11.025723 136.7104   100  a 
#        Ben 13.565411 13.736668 22.091870 16.371157 17.147923 148.0921   100   b
```